# Search for a String in a Struct

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct, while-loop

Ok I having a Problem Getting this to Work, So could some one please help me with this  I am Trying to ask a user to Search for a Station Name and if its is found output it if not then exit..

```
struct Trains 
{
    int Train_Id;                   //train ID
    string Station_Origin;             //Station of Origin
    string Destination_Station;        //Station of Destination
    int Departure_Time ;            //Departure Time
    int Arrival_Time ;              //Arrival Time
};

struct Trains  myArray[10];

struct station
{
    string intermediate_station1;      //intermediate_station1
    int Arrival_time1;             // Arrival time to station1 
    string intermediate_station2;      //intermediate_station2
    int Arrival_time2;             // Arrival time to station2 
    string intermediate_station3;     // intermediate_station1
    int Arrival_time3;             // Arrival time to station3   
};


struct station myArray1[3];

/*****************************************************************************/

int main ()
{
     /*  Setting up Train and Station Information  */ 
    int N_TRAIN;
    int n; 
    int a;

    do 
    {
         cout  << " Enter number of Trains on Track: " <<endl;

         cin >> N_TRAIN;
         cout << endl;        
    }while(N_TRAIN > 10 || N_TRAIN < 0);

    for(n=0; n < N_TRAIN; n++)
    {
        while((cout<<" Enter Train ID: ")&&( (cin>>myArray[n].Train_Id)||myArray[n].Train_Id <0))
        {
            cout<<" Invalid Input! Please Enter Train ID: "<<endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000,'\n'); 
        }

        cout << " Name of Station of Origin: ";
        cin >> myArray[n].Station_Origin;

        cout << " Name of Destination Station: ";
        cin >> myArray[n].Destination_Station;

        while((cout<<"Enter Departure Time: Please Enter 24hr!")&&(!(cin>>myArray[n].Departure_Time)||myArray[n].Departure_Time < 0))
        {
            cout<<" Invalid Input! Enter Departure Time: Please Enter 24hr !"<<endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000,'\n'); 
        }

        while((cout<<" Enter Arrival Time: Please Enter 24hr! ")&&(!(cin>>myArray[n].Arrival_Time)||myArray[n].Arrival_Time < 0))
        {
            cout<<" Invalid Input! Enter Arrival Time: Please Enter 24hr! "<<endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000,'\n');    
        }

        cout << " Name of Station of intermediate station1: ";
        cin >> myArray1[a].intermediate_station1;    

        while((cout<<" Enter Arrival Time For intermediate station1: Please Enter 24hr! ")&&(!(cin>>myArray1[a].Arrival_time1)||myArray1[a].Arrival_time1 < 0))
        {
            cout<<" Invalid Input! Enter Arrival Time: Please Enter 24hr! "<<endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000,'\n'); 
        }

        cout << " Name of Station of intermediate station2: ";
        cin >> myArray1[a].intermediate_station2;


        while((cout<<" Enter Arrival Time For intermediate station2: Please Enter 24hr! ")&&(!(cin>>myArray1[a].Arrival_time2)||myArray1[a].Arrival_time2 < 0))
        {
            cout<<" Invalid Input! Enter Arrival Time For intermediate station2: Please Enter 24hr!"<<endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000,'\n'); 
        }

        cout << " Name of Station of intermediate station3: ";
        cin >> myArray1[a].intermediate_station3;    

        while((cout<<" Enter Arrival Time For intermediate station3: Please Enter 24hr!")&&(!(cin>>myArray1[a].Arrival_time3)||myArray1[a].Arrival_time3 < 0))
        {
            cout<<" Invalid Input! Enter Arrival Time For intermediate station3: Please Enter 24hr!"<<endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000,'\n'); 
        }
   }

    /* SEARCHING BY STATION NAME: */        
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        int origin;
        int result;

        for (n=0; n < N_TRAIN ;n++)
        {       

            cout << " Enter the Name of Departure Station: " ;
            cin >> origin;

            origin = searchfs();
            if (origin = myArray[n].Station_Origin )
               cout << "Trains Departs " << " " <<myArray[n].Station_Origin << "at" << " " << myArray[n].Departure_Time << " " << " Hours " <<endl;

            else if   (origin = myArray[n].Destination_Station )
                cout << "Trains Departs " << " " <<myArray[n].Destination_Station << "at" << " " << myArray[n].Departure_Time << " " << " Hours " <<endl;

            else if  (origin =  myArray1[a].intermediate_station1 )      
                cout << "Trains Departs " << " " <<  myArray1[a].intermediate_station1<< "at" << " " << myArray1[a].Arrival_time1 << " " << " Hours " <<endl;

            else if  (origin =  myArray1[a].intermediate_station2 )
                cout << "Trains Departs " << " " <<  myArray1[a].intermediate_station2 << "at" << " " << myArray1[a].Arrival_time2 << " " << " Hours " <<endl;

            else if  (origin =  myArray1[a].intermediate_station3 )
                cout << "Trains Departs " << " " <<  myArray1[a].intermediate_station3<< "at" << " " << myArray1[a].Arrival_time3 << " " << " Hours " <<endl;

            else if (result == -1)
                cout << " Train doesnt not Depart at "<< " " << origin << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's way too much code to dump on us, and way too few details about what didn't work about your approach.

Comment: Furthermore, you could replace the HTML entities by the actual character - this would make your code much more readable. E.g. instead of `&lt;` simply write `<`

Comment: @Thilo - sorry, that was actually one of my original edits - used the wrong formatting options.

Comment: also, don't put `cout`s in loops conditions, that's just confusing.

Comment: What are the original requirements?  Is the structure really suppose to contain 3 stations?

Comment: Yes it is meant to have a Origin Station and a Destination Station to make this easy on the Program each record has 3 intermediate stations.

Answer (score 2):

In several places it looks like you have assignment (single `=`) where you meant to test for equality (double `==`) like the following example:

```
if (origin = myArray[n].Station_Origin)
```

In addition, `Station_Origin` and `intermediate_station1/2/3` are defined as `std::string` while `origin` is defined as an `int`. You're attempting to assign or compare a `string` to an `int`.

Comment: What do i need to do to fix that Search to be able to Work as i have every thing else working but not that part.                                                                           What i would like the Program to do is give the user a choice of inputting a Station Name if the Station is their out put it if not go the the next String and do a Search on that String if its not there go to the next String untill the Station is found if its not found Exit..

Comment: @David: Based only on the code you've shown, in the places you want to compare two values use the `==` operator instead of `=`. In addition you probably want to change `origin` to a string variable. That also means changing your `searchfs()` function to return a string.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what *is* happening, so we can only guess, by scanning over the code.  One thing that strikes me is:

```
for(n=0; n < N_TRAIN; n++)
{
    ...
}      
else if (choice == 3)
{
}
```

and `choice` is undefined.
How about you solve as many error messages as possible, and then tell us the specific ones that are stumping you.

Comment: OK i change Origin from int to String.. What i cant figure out is with  "origin = Searchfs()" i don't know what i need to place within the ()